# images is not found when passing image name to vue component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to create input component dynamically as I need for each input a specific icon for it.
Icon is set to the input as a background image and it works when I use it directly in css like so `background-image: url(../../assets/icons/email.svg);`

But when I pass the name of the icon for the component, the app says that it is not found!
[image]

```html
    <template>
        <section class="input-box">
            <input class="input-field" type="text" :style="imgIcon">
            <label>{{title}}</label>
        </section>
    </template>

    <script>
      export default {
        props: ["title", "bgImg"],
        computed: {
          imgIcon() {
            return 'background-image: url(./assets/icons/' + this.bgImg + ')';
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

and when I pass the name as a string

```html
<custome-input title="password" bgImg="'p_key.svg'"></custome-input>
```

the error is solved but nothing shows!

What is wrong exactly?

Comment: you should not use relative path with vue. try to use the `@` alias instead. It's an alias for the root directory.

Comment: @Nicolas I tried this `return 'background-image: url(@/assets/icons/' + this.bgImg + '.svg)';` and it didn't work too

Comment: I think the url needs to be in quotes too. : `return 'background-image: url(\'@/assets/icons/' + this.bgImg + '.svg\')'`

Comment: didn't work too. still saying that file not found :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `require` when binding to a dynamic image:

```js
computed: {
  imgIcon() {
    try {
      return 'background-image: url(' + require('@/assets/icons/' + this.bgImg) + ')';
    } catch(error) {
      return ''; 
    }
  }
}
```

The error you mentioned in comments is because part of the path is a prop that may not be defined yet when this first calculates, so it's wrapped in a `try` block.

Comment: This worked! but when using `@` it gives an error so I needed to use dots to locate the folder. what causes this problem?

Comment: this error `Can't resolve '@/assets/icons'`. this path equals to  `../../assets/icons`

Comment: Ah ok, I updated the answer.  `@` is an alias for the `src` directory

Comment: One more question. when I try to use the component without passing the name of the image. the whole component disappeared and I get this error `Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './'` . sometimes I might not need to use a background image. Is there any solution other than changing the styles for the other use of the component?

Comment: Ok. your last edit to the answer worked too for my question. thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use images from templates you need to use `@`and the `url` should be a string.

```
export default {
  props: ["title", "bgImg"],
  computed: {
    imgIcon() {
      return `background-image: url('@/assets/icons/${this.bgImg}')`;
    }
  }
}
```